# How to get pinned threads first in collection

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get pinned threads in a collection where I also get latest replied to threads as well. Haven't found anything anywhere and could not figure it out so I'm here to ask all of you. Please impart your wisdom. Here is what I have so far.

```
        $threads = Thread::all()->sortByDesc(function($thread) {
            $replies = $thread->replies->sortByDesc('created_at');
            $newestResponse = Carbon::minValue();
            if (!empty($replies->toArray())) {
              $newestResponse = $newestResponse->max($replies->first()->created_at);
            }
            return $newestResponse->max($thread->created_at);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand that you want only the latest reply for each thread.  Based on this, I would create a relationship specifically for this task.

**Thread.php**

```php
// add a new Eloquent relationship
public function latestReply()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Reply::class)->latest();
}
```

Then use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to perform the query.

```php
$threads = Thread::with('latestReply')
    ->orderBy('pinned','desc')
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

Generally speaking, it's better to perform your queries at the database level.  Retrieving `all()` results and processing as a Collection is often significantly slower and should be avoided.

Comment: When someone replies to a thread, the thread gets put on top, is right now, the functionality of the code -- what I want is to place pinned threads above the whole process. (I appreciate your insight)

Comment: How do you determine if a thread is pinned? Is the there a database field (e.g., `is_pinned`)?

Comment: So you want all replies for a thread, but pinned replies first?  The rest in descending chronological order?

Comment: I want all threads with the latest reply, but the pinned threads first, no matter what.

Comment: See my updates.  It's just a small change, but you now have two `orderBy()` clauses.  Order by pin status, then creation date.  Or order however you like so long as `pinned` is first.

Comment: I tried it, but the reply I created 3 minutes ago is not falling towards the top after the pinned threads.

Comment: So a reply should push a thread to the top, but not above pinned?  I think I get it now, but may need to think about the method.

Comment: Yes exactly! That's what I need :)

Comment: Is there some specific reason this needs to be one query?  It would be much simpler to run two separate queries (pinned and not pinned).

Comment: Good point, then I could just place it separately within the blade template files as well?